# How to use faker gem to generate fake food names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

I have read up several tutorials, but I am still unsure how to do what I want, therefore I am sorry if it sounds dump. I have an active record called "Sandwitches", which has as attributes: *name*, *price* and *availability*. As I want to generate fake data for it, I am not quite sure how I can achieve something like this, because the *name* attribute *faker* can generate stands for names of persons. I would like for instance to generate names for the sandwitches, like "Club Sandwitch" or "Pesto with Feta Cheese". Is there anyway to do this with *faker gem* ? Or basically could I use any other gem to achieve that?

I apppreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take a look at the faker gem here: https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/lib/faker/default/food.rb  (note, I am not affiliated w/ faker development) You can see there is a food module. So try this:

```
>> Faker::Food.dish
=> "Tiramisù"
>> Faker::Food.dish
=> "Mushroom Risotto"
>> Faker::Food.vegetables
=> "Radish"
```

I also saw a dessert module and some others that looked interesting. Go up one or two trees in github's directory structure to see other options. Faker does a lot of things!

Edit: Also, your AR table should be "Sandwiches", not "Sandwitches"  ;)  They're not witches with sand powers, they're food w/ bread ;p

Another Edit: I don't see an option *specifically* for sandwiches. But maybe since this is for fake data you can just use the dish option.

Final Edit I swear:  You could "fake" a sandwich with something like:

```
breads = ["Brioche", "Rye", "Whole Wheat"] # Add more breads here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_breads can help
ingredients = (1..(rand(3)+1)).map{rand > 0.5 ? Faker::Food.ingredient : Faker::Food.vegetables}
sandwich = "#{ingredients.to_sentence} on #{breads.sample(1).first}"
```

Which can return results like:

```
=> "Buckwheat Flour on Rye"
=> "Broccoli and Jicama on Whole Wheat"
=> "Peppers on Rye"
=> "Chia Seeds on Rye"
=> "Pecan Nut and Anchovies on Brioche"
=> "Arugula on Rye"
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the [@nzifnab answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54353729/2109121) you can also dry your specs and organize your own custom fakes (based on [@nzifnab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54353729/2109121) code)

*spec/support/faker/sandwich.rb*

```
module Faker
  class Sandwich
    class << self
      def title
        "#{ingredients.to_sentence} on #{breads.sample(1).first}"
      end

      def breads
        ["Brioche", "Rye", "Whole Wheat"] # Add more breads here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_breads can help
      end

      def ingredients
        (1..(rand(3)+1)).map{rand > 0.5 ? Faker::Food.ingredient : Faker::Food.vegetables}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*spec/models/sandwiches_spec.rb*

```
describe 'Sandwiches' do
  it 'contains name' do
    # some checks...
    expect(Faker::Sandwich.title).not_to be_empty
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it's `expect(...).not_to`, not `to_not`? Unless both work? I've always used `not_to` in rspec.

Answer (score 1):

model name = Item.

db column name =  (name,price,category_id,image_id,short_description,long_description,is_active,preparation_time,calorie_count, meal_type_id,cuisine_id,spicy_level,is_new,is_bestseller)

in /seed.rb

```
100.times do 
    Item.create([{
        name:Faker::Food.dish,
        price:Faker::Number.positive(5, 30),
        category_id:Faker::Number.positive(1, 10),
        image_id:Faker::Number.positive(1, 20),
        short_description:Faker::Lorem.words(rand(2..5)).join(' '),
        long_description:Faker::Lorem.words(rand(2..10)).join(' '),
        is_active:Faker::Boolean.boolean,
        preparation_time:Faker::Number.positive(10, 90),
        serves:Faker::Number.between(1, 3),
        calorie_count:Faker::Number.between(20, 500),
        meal_type_id:Faker::Number.positive(1, 4),
        cuisine_id:Faker::Number.positive(1, 10),
        spicy_level:Faker::Number.between(1, 3),
        is_new:Faker::Boolean.boolean,
        is_bestseller:Faker::Boolean.boolean
    }])
end
```

and then in terminal

```
rake db:seed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can visit below link for documentation of `faker` gem.
  https://github.com/stympy/faker

For Example,

```
5.times.do
 name = Faker::Name.first_name
 price = Faker::Name.price
end
```